# error while updating property 'title' of a view managed by: RNScreenStackHeaderConfig (react native)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

My app has a home screen (HomeScreen.js) with a bottom tab navigator, and it is nested within a stack navigator in App.js. Whenever I try and navigate to the profile screen from the home screen I get the following error:[image: Error]

This error only occurs when I try and set headerTitle to a custom component in App.js. Does anyone know how I can set the header of ProfileScreen to a custom component correctly?

My navigation structure looks like this:

- `Stack.Navigator`

  - `Tab.Navigator`

    - `Food (screen)`
    - `Friends (screen)`
    - `Lists (screen)`
  - `Profile (screen)`

I am able to set a custom component as the header in `Tab.Navigator`, but not in `Profile`

Let me know if more information is needed.

App.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "react-native-screens/native-stack";
import HomeArea from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "./screens/ProfileScreen";
import NavBar from "./componets/NavBar";
import BackSVG from "./assets/BackSVG";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="HomeArea"
          component={HomeArea}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ProfileScreen"
          component={ProfileScreen}
          options={{
            headerTitle: props => {
              return <Text>Test</Text>;
            }
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

HomeScreen.js:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import FoodScreen from "../screens/FoodScreen";
import FriendsScreen from "../screens/FriendsScreen";
import Lunchlists from "../screens/Lunchlists";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import FoodSVG from "../assets/FoodSVG";
import ListSVG from "../assets/ListSVG";
import FriendsSVG from "../assets/FriendsSVG";
import NavBar from "../componets/NavBar";
import UserSVG from "../assets/UserSVG";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarStyle: styles.navBar,
        tabBarActiveTintColor: "#fff",
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        header: () => (
          <NavBar
            symbolRight={UserSVG}
            symbolLeft={View}
            rightPressEvent={() => navigation.navigate("ProfileScreen")}
          />
        )
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Food"
        component={FoodScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Food",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {
            return <FoodSVG width={size} height={size} color={color} />;
          }
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Friends"
        component={FriendsScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Friends",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {
            return <FriendsSVG width={size} height={size} color={color} />;
          }
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Lunchlists"
        component={Lunchlists}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Lunchlists",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {
            return <ListSVG width={size} height={size} color={color} />;
          }
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  navBar: {
    backgroundColor: "#5A4664"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imported createNativeStackNavigator from the wrong package. In App.js I instead imported it using `import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";`, which solved my problems.